# Adding specific address to an ICS file

Tags: php, laravel, file, icalendar

I am working in PHP laravel and I generate an ICS file when I am sending notifications to my users.
How can I add address details?

I am using LOCATION: to add my shop name. But I want to add the adress of the shop also by using maps or something else to get the address of the shop.

Comment: So it sounds like your real question has nothing to do with ICS files specifically, and is actually about how to retrieve an address from something like Google Maps API, by searching for a name? (What you do with it after that is a separate point).

Comment: For example if my location is Apple Store Amsterdam I want to generate the address details in my ICS file and maybe by using an API

Comment: You'll certainly need an API, yes. So it actually is _two_ questions: 1) how to use some mapping API to get an address (or a link to a map application - you need to decide what you are trying to export) based on a placename, and 2) how to present that data usefully in the ICS format. Those are two separate issues, really.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/text-search is likely to be the endpoint to call if you want to use Google Maps. See also https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/op-overview. Other Map APIs may have similar endpoints, you can research it

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but I found a reference that seemed to show this format would work.

```
LOCATION;ALTREP="your-url":Visual Text Here
```

e.g.

```
LOCATION;ALTREP="https://www.google.com/maps/place/CN+Tower/@43.6425701,-79.3896317,17z/data=!3m2!4b1!5s0x882b34d819a55ff7:0xad7cf7bcaf4e239b!4m6!3m5!1s0x882b34d68bf33a9b:0x15edd8c4de1c7581!8m2!3d43.6425662!4d-79.3870568!16zL20vMDF0d3M?entry=ttu":CN Tower
```

As for generating a link to a location, you can use this link format:

```
https://www.google.ca/maps/search/your-address
```

e.g.

```
https://www.google.ca/maps/search/123%20Yonge%20St,%20Toronto,%20Canada
```

Comment: Thankyou but do you know how I can generate those urls just by a place name in my code?

Comment: updated the answer to include making a link. I'm in Canada, so I've used the `.ca` domain, but it should work with the `.com` domain or other countries too.

Comment: Ok...but going to `https://www.google.ca/maps/search/123%20Yonge%20St,%20Toronto,%20Canada` for example brings up a HTML page with the map inside it. It doesn't generate a URL directly. I think the OP wants to do this programatically

Comment: Yeah if you want something more than this, you'll need to get an API key to call methods to generate links programatically. The /search/ link just works out of the box as a default solution.